# Conditional aggregation - once for each key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an aggregation problem that can probably best be described with some example data.

Below is a dataset with transports, identified by `trp_no`. Each such transport is loaded in a container. A container may hold multiple such transports, and in this example any transport may only be loaded in one container.

```
TRP_NO TRANSPORT_VOLUME COUNTRY CONTAINER_ID CONTAINER_MAX
------ ---------------- ------- ------------ -------------
     1               10   SE         A            80
     2               20   SE         A            80
     3               30   SE         A            80
```

The following keys (or functional dependencies) exists in the dataset:

```
trp_no       -> {transport_volume, country, container_id}
container_id -> {container_max}
```

I want to calculate Filling Rate per Country, which is calculated as transported volume divided by the capacity. Translated into SQL, this becomes:

```
with sample_data as(
   select 1 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 2 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 3 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual
)  
select country
      ,sum(transport_volume) / sum(container_max)
  from sample_data
 group 
    by country;
```

...which returns (10+20+30) / (80+80+80) = 25%. Which is **not** what I want, because all transports used the **same** container_id, and my query triple-counted the capacity.

The result I want is (10+20+30) / 80 = 75%.
So, I only want to sum container_max once for each container_id within the group.

Any ideas on how to fix the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses Rachcha's bigger sample set, which I think is necessary to really test this problem.

```
with sample_data as(
    select 1 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
    select 2 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
    select 3 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
    select 4 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
    select 5 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
    select 6 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
    select 7 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual union all
    select 8 as trp_no, 15 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual union all
    select 9 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual
),
country_container_sum as
(
    select country, sum(container_max) sum_container_max
    from
    (
        select distinct country, container_id, container_max
        from sample_data
    )
    group by country
),
country_transport_volume_sum as
(
    select country, sum(transport_volume) sum_transport_volume
    from sample_data
    group by country
)
select country, sum_transport_volume / sum_container_max rate
from country_container_sum
join country_transport_volume_sum using (country);
```

Results:

```
COUNTRY   RATE
-------   ----
SE        0.666666666666667
AU        0.9
```

Comment: This, I think, is the best solution for the given problem, provided the denormalized nature of the sample data the OP has given.

Comment: Thanks, this gives the desired result. I was hoping I could find a solution with analytic functions that lets me use the same SUM() construct and simply changing what I GROUP BY. With your suggested construct I have to rewrite multiple parts of the query depending on what I choose to group by. Still I think this is a good answer with simplicity/performance trade off.

Answer (score 1):

This approach, while other ways are simpler, uses analytic functions. I only edit with this approach because, while jonearle's response gives you the correct output, you responded saying that you wanted an approach that uses analytic functions. This approach uses analytic functions.

However, you cannot use aggregate functions nor the group by clause with analytic functions (the idea itself doesn't make sense), without adding a second layer to the query. Depending on what other similar queries you want to run, this *might* be easier for you as a template query, however it's hard to tell without knowing what other similar queries you're running.

```
with sample_data as(
    select 1 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
    select 2 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
    select 3 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
    select 4 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
    select 5 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
    select 6 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
    select 7 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual union all
    select 8 as trp_no, 15 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual union all
    select 9 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual
)
, sub as(
select x.*, sum(x.cont_mx_n) over (partition by country order by country, container_id, trp_no) as cont_mx
from(
select country
      , container_id
      , trp_no
      , sum(transport_volume) over (partition by country order by country, container_id, trp_no) as transp_vol
      , case when lead(container_id,1) over (partition by country order by country, container_id, trp_no) = container_id
             then null
             else container_max end as cont_mx_n
      , row_number() over (partition by country order by country, container_id, trp_no) as maxchk
  from sample_data
order by country, container_id, trp_no) x)
select country, transp_vol / cont_mx as rate
from sub y
where y.maxchk = (select max(x.maxchk) from sub x where x.country = y.country);
```

Result of the above is:

```
AU  0.9
SE  0.666666666666667
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd have to wrap this statement within another SELECT / Group by. Try changing one 'A' to 'B' and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Ronnis if you change just one of the 3 rows to B, you're adding another container, so you'll want to show container in the SELECT list, that's all. That way you see which row reflects which container. Is that what you mean? I don't know why you would need a second layer to the query. If I'm not understanding what you're saying, please edit w/ another sample set of rows to illustrate. Thanks

Comment: I updated the query if that's what you meant. I thought you were saying that you thought you needed a select statement on top of the select statement., which I don't believe is true.

Comment: @ShWiVeL, The above query repeats the country once for each container. So in order to get a result set in which country->filling rate, I would need to wrap this query in another query.

Comment: @Ronnis The above calculates the rate by country using analytic functions. (edited)

Answer (score 1):

I added a little more sample data for illustrating a minor fix in the query that solved it-

```
with sample_data as(
   select 1 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 2 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 3 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 4 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
   select 5 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
   select 6 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'B' as container_id, 100 as container_max from dual union all
   select 7 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual union all
   select 8 as trp_no, 15 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual union all
   select 9 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'AU' as country, 'C' as container_id, 50 as container_max from dual
)  
select country
      ,sum(transport_volume / container_max) -- Note the change here
  from sample_data
 group 
    by country;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
COUNTRY SUM(TRANSPORT_VOLUME/CONTAINER_MAX)
------- -----------------------------------
SE                                     1.35
AU                                       .9
```

**EDIT:**

As I see your sample data, I think you need a bit of normalization in your database. The columns for a container and columns for a transport trip should reside in separate tables like this:\

```
TABLE CONTAINER (
    container_id        VARCHAR2 / INTEGER,
    container_max       INTEGER,
    country             VARCHAR2
)

TABLE trip (
    trp_no              INTEGER,
    transport_volume    INTEGER,
    container_id        VARCHAR2 / INTEGER REFERENCES container.container_id
)
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to specifically sum up the transport volumes according to the containers' capacities, you can use something like the following query (with the same sample data table `sample_data` from above):

```
  select d.country,
         (select sum(t.transport_volume)
            from sample_data t
           where t.country = d.country) /
         (select sum(c.container_max)
            from (  select country, container_max
                      from sample_data
                  group by container_id, country, container_max
                 ) c
           where c.country = d.country) as col1
    from sample_data d
group by d.country;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
COUNTRY        COL1
------- -----------
SE      0.666666667
AU              0.9
```

Comment: I would expect SE to be 0.667: (10+20+30+10+20+30)/(80+100).  It's good that you added more sample data it should help clarify the requirements.

Comment: @jonearles: Edited my answer, please check.

Comment: @Rachcha, The first output is wrong for country=SE. I will check your second edit ASAP. Thanks! Regarding the comment about normalization: The real model has separate entities, but since you have to join them the problem of double counting issue is the same regardless of normalization :)

Comment: @Ronnis- Ok then, I guess you can derive code from my Edit 2 part by simply replacing the subqueries with your table names. I'd still say it would've been a lot more easier and accurate if you had posted the sample data as two separate tables. Anyways, you know what to do, if any problem, let us know.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

```
with sample_data as(
   select 1 as trp_no, 10 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 2 as trp_no, 20 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual union all
   select 3 as trp_no, 30 as transport_volume, 'SE' as country, 'A' as container_id, 80 as container_max from dual
)  
select country
      ,sum(transport_volume) / container_max
  from sample_data
 group 
    by country, container_max;
```

The result was the expected.

ps: some nice guy remembered us about also grouping container_id, which won't affect the result in this case, but might be needed in other cases :-)